# Force restart Apache in CentOS 7 after clearing logs

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

I have the following directory which stores domain logs filled with 17GB of errors:

```
/usr/local/apache/logs
```

Every 2 months I have to delete the logs as they get grow big like this.

After clearing the logs, I have to restart Apache for the logs to really get cleared using:

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

When I try the above command after clearing, I get the following error:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I can overcome this by restarting the whole web server but this is really not good. This happens only after deleting the logs. I assume just deleting the files like this is not the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/logrotate.d/httpd logrotate configuration file provided with httpd in centos 7 do almost the same action(see below).

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
missingok
notifempty
sharedscripts
delaycompress
postrotate
    /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
endscript
}
```

It executes /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service after the log rotation.
Perhaps your http service have been another problems, in this case the output of "systemctl status httpd" or checking /var/log/httpd/error_log could give more information.